# Title attribute value appears on rollover, how do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, title, alt

Below is a JS fiddle that I have been using to implement a tooltip on my website.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62NT7/)

However when I implement this on my website, the title attribute value appears on rollover (like an alt attribute) as well as the tooltip. I need it not to do this! The actual code from my website is below.

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {  
  $(this)
    .css('z-index', '10')
    .find('img').addClass("hover")
    .stop()
    .animate({
       marginTop: '-150px',
       marginLeft: '-150px',
       top: '50%',
       left: '50%',
       width: '300px',
       height: '300px',
       padding: '20px'

     }, 200, function() {

        var $this = $(this),
        h = $this.height();
        $caption = $('<div class="caption">' + this.title  + '</div>')
            .css('top', h.toString() + 'px');
            $this.after($caption);

      }); 

   }, function() {

 $('.caption').remove();
 $(this)
.css('z-index', '0')
.find('img').removeClass("hover")
.stop()
.animate({

    marginTop: '0',
    marginLeft: '0',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    padding: '5px'

 }, 400);
 });
 });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="thumb">
<li> <img src="slide1image.png" width="200" height="229" title="come join us and have   lots of fun with our clowns, tigers and magician" /></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `title` attribute then.

Use `data-title` as the attribute name and access it with the `$this.data('title')`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/62NT7/1/

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly on PC but on an ipad the text does not show any ideas why the data-title tag doesn't work on iPad?

Comment: are you sure it is not a case of the hover not getting fired ? (*see if `touchstart`/`touchend` work better*)

Comment: I am pretty sure as the caption box opens just without the text, the text is in the data-title tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the essence of what you want to do is to prevent the default behavior of hovering over an image, the following should take care of it:

```
$('img').on('hover', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/62NT7/2/)

Other ways of resolving this include:

```
- removing the attribute: $('img').removeAttr('title')
- saving the value to a data attribute and removing it: $('img').data('title', function() { return this.title; }).removeAttr('title');
- editing your markup so that you use a data attribute instead of title attribute - as @GabyakaG.Petrioli's answer.
```